# About Pointers and arrays and types and casting

Tags: c, pointers, char, int

Say I have the following problem:

```
main(void) {
int * p;
int nums [3] = {1,5,9};
char c [3] = {'s','t','u'};
p =  nums [2];
*p = (int) *c;
}
```

What does the last line mean?

Answer (score 1):

Let's break it down: `*p = (int) *c;`

`c` is a char array.

`*c` is the first element of the char array, because `c[0]` = `*(c+0)` = `*(c)` = `*c`

`(int) *c` casts the first element of the char array `c` to an integer. This is required, because with...

`*p = (int) *c` you assign the to an integer casted char to the content of pointer `p`.

Answer (score 1):

This code will not work, or will cause problems if it does.

the line;
    p = nums[2];

sets the value of the pointer p to the value 9. This is not likely a legal value for your pointer. If it were, then the memory location 9 would be set to 115 which is the integer value of 's'.

Comment: I meant set p = &nums[2]

Answer (score 0):

`*c` → [Decay `c` to pointer-to-first-element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/3425536), and access the pointed-to value. Same as `c[0]`.
`(int) *c` →  cast that value to `int`.
`*p = (int) *c` →  assign that to what `p` points to.

Comment: But when you say *c...it is an array. So does it always point to the first index?

Comment: So *c means the pointer to the memory location of the first index of the array?

Comment: An array is an array, not a pointer. An array doesn't point anywhere. But an array can decay to a pointer to the first element in the array, as happens when the `*` dereference operator is applied to the array name. Thus `*c` evaluates to the first element of the array, and is identical to writing `c[0]`.

Comment: *c = c [0] is what you are saying

Comment: Yes, when you define an array, the array name is a pointer to the array's first element, so in your specific example for instance, nums is a pointer to num[0]. That is to say *nums = nums[0].

Comment: @MPI_What No, the array name is not a pointer. The array name is a name for the array, and the array itself is an array, not a pointer.

Comment: An array name is essentially a constant pointer to the first element of the array...

Comment: @MPI_What Time to learn the basics. An array name can __decay__ to a pointer-to-the-first-element when it is handled like a pointer (e.g. dereferenced), but it __is__ not a pointer. See [Is array name a pointer in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1641957/3425536).

Comment: Very well, I accept. My point was more that they can be treated as the same thing though. I'll butt out now ...

Comment: Sometimes yes, sometimes no.

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues in this code, let's address them first.

- Firstly, `main(void)` is not conforming code. You need to change that to `int main(void).`
- Secondly, `p =  nums [2];` is wrong. `p` is of type `int *`, and `nums[2]` is of type `int`. You may not assign an `int` to a `int *` and expect something fruitful to happen. Maybe what you meant to write is `p =  &nums[2];`. Without this modification, going further will invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) as you will try to access a memory location that is *invalid* to your program.

Then, coming to your question,

```
*p = (int) *c;
```

it basically dereference `c`<sup>NOTE</sup> to get the value, then cast it to an `int` type and store into the memory location pointed by `p`. However, in `C`, this casting is not required. The above statement is equivalent to

```
*p = *c;
```

anyway.

---

NOTE: Array name decays to the pointer to the first element of the array, i.e., in this code, using `c` is the same as `&c[0]`, roughly.